# Splitting summation of sequences to parts

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty, (b_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be two sequences of real numbers.
When looking at $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n+b_n$, is it always possible to split the summation to $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n$?
Does it matter whether the sequences converge/diverge?

Comment: Try $a_n=1, b_n=-1$.

Comment: @lulu Can it be generalized? Or for some cases it works and for others it doesn't?

Comment: Can what be generalized?  Rearranging the terms in infinite series is very tricky.  It works if the series connverges absolutely, but it's complicated otherwise.  See [Riemann's Rearrangement Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem)

Comment: @lulu why can’t one use sum of limit is limit of sum provide it exists see my answer

Comment: Yes, if the two series separately converge then you are good.

Answer (score 0):

You can not always do so for example you can let $a_{n}=1$ and $b_{n}=-1$ then $\sum a_{n}$ and $\sum 
b_{n}$ diverge but $\sum a_{n} +b_{n}$ converges .It’s not even true if the terms are all positive. 
It is true if both $\sum a_{n}$ and $\sum b_{n}$ converge this is because sum of limit is limit of sum provided they both exist .

Comment: It also works for $\sum_{n=2}^\infty[\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n(n-1)}]$ even though $\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{n}$ is divergent. Doesn't it?

Comment: @Lilo What works ?

Comment: $\sum_{n=2}^\infty[\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n(n-1)}] = \sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{n} +\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{n(n-1)}$

Comment: No the first sum does not converge since the harmonic series diverges @Lilo

Comment: It doesn't converge, and yet it's possible to split the summation

Comment: @Lilo how can you split the summation if one of series does not converge what meaning does adding  2 non convergent series have ?

Comment: This way you can prove that the left hand side of the equation diverges, if you split it to two parts and show that one of the parts diverges

Comment: @Lilo that’s not true $a_{n}=1$ and $b_{n}=-1$ as given in the answer  is the usual counter example

Comment: I meant to say that if one part converges and the other diverges then the whole expression diverges

Comment: @Lilo which parts ?

Comment: $\sum_{n=2}^\infty[\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n(n-1)}] = \sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{n} - \sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{n(n-1)}$
The first part diverges since it's the harmonic series, the second part is the telescoping series and therefore converges. And the whole expression diverges

Comment: @Lilo which ‘’ whole expression’’?

Comment: $\sum_{n=2}^\infty[\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n(n-1)}]$

Comment: @lilo again the example given in my answer is a counter example.